# Cannot retrieve record type using metadata service

Tags: picklist, metadata, record-type, mdapi

Hello I am trying to retrieve a record type to update its picklist values but whenever i try to do this it returns a weird object which has most of its values as null and I tried to use a name of a record that does not exist and it returned the same result so I think it cannot find the record type that I specifying for some reason . Here is the code that I am using

```apex
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();             
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.Metadata[] mdRecordType = service.readMetadata(
        'RecordType', new String[]{'test_2'}
                ).getRecords();
System.debug(mdRecordType);
```

and here is the debug output

> 12:12:38.1 (565683411)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|(RecordType:[Metadata.fullName=null, active=null, active_type_info=(active, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), businessProcess=null, businessProcess_type_info=(businessProcess, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), compactLayoutAssignment=null, compactLayoutAssignment_type_info=(compactLayoutAssignment, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), description=null, description_type_info=(description, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), field_order_type_info=(fullName, active, businessProcess, compactLayoutAssignment, description, label, picklistValues), fullName=null, fullName_type_info=(fullName, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), label=null, label_type_info=(label, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), picklistValues=null, picklistValues_type_info=(picklistValues, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), type=RecordType, type_att_info=(xsi:type)])

Comment: Since RecordType's are part of an object, wouldn't you need to specify the sobject name in the RecordType name, e.g. `Account.test_2` instead of just `test_2`?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn yes thank you that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecordType's are part of an SObject (custom or standard) and cannot be retrieved without fully qualifying the RecordType with the SObject name as well. So, your code needs to specify the SObject to which the RecordType belongs to, for example:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();             
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.Metadata[] mdRecordType = service.readMetadata(
        'RecordType', new String[]{'Account.test_2'}
                ).getRecords();
System.debug(mdRecordType);
```

Where `Account` is the SObject and `test_2` is the RecordType.